# node.js update mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using the node.js mysql package where I can create a connection and after connection.query(..) .., close the connection.

I have a collection of rows that I want to update in mysql database, and I don't know if the rows exist or not. Here I have two solutions but I don't know which one is better:

1. delete all the rows I want to update in mysql database and insert all rows using one connection.query(..)..

   sudo code:   1. delete from table where id = ..[],
                2. insert into table set ...
2. check each row that I want to update/insert, if the id exists in mysql database, then send query to update, otherwise insert.

   sudo code: 1. for each row in list
              2. check if the row exists in mysql
              3. if exists, then send query to update;
                 if not exists, then send query to insert

for the second solution, I concerned that might be too time-consuming. Any one have some suggestions? What is the best way to do this?
I'm new to these stuff so I don't know if it is better to send multiple queries inside a for loop, especially in node each connection.query is a function with callback. Which one will have better overall performance?, or any other solutions?

Comment: it's mysql: do both at the same time: `insert .. on duplicate key update`. problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `insert ... on duplicate key update`

Example:

`` insert into `tableName` (col1, col2, col3) values ( 'v1', 'v2', 'v3') on dupicate key update `col3`='v3' ``

*This wouldn't work if the key in this case is an auto_increment counter.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html